Isru Chag Ba'avotim - what's it about?
Background:
Near the end of Hallel
אֵ֤ל ׀ ה' וַיָּ֢אֶ֫ר לָ֥נוּ אִסְרוּ־חַ֥ג בַּעֲבֹתִ֑ים עַד־קַ֝רְנ֗וֹת הַמִּזְבֵּֽחַ׃
Hashem is G-d; he has given us light;
bind the festal offering to the horns of the altar with cords.
The verse seems very obscure. When do we ever tie a korbon to the altar? And why the corners?
Rashi in Chullin says
מחמשה ועד עשרה טמא שבו קושרין את הפסחים זכר לפסח מצרים דכתי' אסרו חג בעבותים וגו' וכתיב והיה לכם למשמרת
[these lengths of rope were used] when they would tie their Korbon Pesachs [to the bed], in remembrance of the Pesach in Egypt, as is written, אסרו חג בעבותים וגו', tie the korbon with ropes..., והיה לכם למשמרת, and you will guard it...
Rashi says that the verse doesn't mean it was tied to the altar, but tied to keep it safe, in preparation for bringing it to the altar. Maybe he understands the word "עד" to mean, "until": [keep it safe] until we get it all the way there, the blood on the corners.
The gemara in Sukkah 45a-b gives three drashos on the verse:

אָמַר רַבִּי אֲבָהוּ: מַאי קְרָאָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אִסְרוּ חַג
בַּעֲבוֹתִים עַד קַרְנוֹת הַמִּזְבֵּחַ״.
אָמַר רַבִּי אֲבָהוּ אָמַר
רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר: כׇּל הַנּוֹטֵל לוּלָב בְּאִגּוּדוֹ וַהֲדַס
בַּעֲבוֹתוֹ, מַעֲלֶה עָלָיו הַכָּתוּב כְּאִילּוּ בָּנָה מִזְבֵּחַ
וְהִקְרִיב עָלָיו קׇרְבָּן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר:
Rabbi Abbahu said: What is
the verse that alludes to the fact that the branches must lean one
cubit over the top of the altar? It is as it is stated: “Encircle
[isru] with branches on the Festival until the horns of the altar”
(Psalms 118:27), indicating that willow branches should surround the
horns of the altar. That is facilitated by standing the branches on
the base.
Rabbi Abbahu said that
Rabbi Elazar said: With regard to anyone who takes a lulav in its
binding and a myrtle branch in its dense-leaved form, the verse
ascribes him credit as though he built an altar and sacrificed an
offering upon it, as it is stated: אִסְרוּ חַג בַּעֲבוֹתִים עַד קַרְנוֹת הַמִּזְבֵּחַ.
“Bind [isru] with dense-leaved branches [ba’avotim] on
the Festival until the horns of the altar” (Psalms 118:27), which
alludes to both the binding of the lulav and to the myrtle branch,
referred to in the Torah as the branch of a dense-leaved tree [anaf
etz avot].
אָמַר רַבִּי
יִרְמְיָה מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן יוֹחַי, וְרַבִּי יוֹחָנָן
מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן הַמָּחוֹזִי מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן
הַמָּכוֹתִי: כׇּל הָעוֹשֶׂה אִיסּוּר לֶחָג בַּאֲכִילָה וּשְׁתִיָּה,
מַעֲלֶה עָלָיו הַכָּתוּב כְּאִילּוּ בָּנָה מִזְבֵּחַ וְהִקְרִיב עָלָיו
קׇרְבָּן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אִסְרוּ חַג בַּעֲבוֹתִים עַד קַרְנוֹת
הַמִּזְבֵּחַ״.
Rabbi Yirmeya said in the name of Rabbi Shimon ben Yoḥai,
and Rabbi Yoḥanan said in the name of Rabbi Shimon HaMeḥozi, who said
in the name of Rabbi Yoḥanan HaMakkoti: With regard to anyone who
establishes an addition [issur] to the Festival on the day after the
Festival by eating and drinking, the verse ascribes him credit as
though he built an altar and sacrificed an offering upon it, as it is
stated: “Add [isru] to the Festival with fattened animals [ba’avotim]
until the horns of the altar.”

So that's four different meanings to the verse, on seemingly different topics.
Rashi in Pesachim 119a has maybe a combination:
אסרו חג בעבותים - הביאו זבחים ושלמים הרבה לשמוח:
Bring many zevachim and shelamim for simcha.
Not sure how he's reading it exactly.
Question: Does someone suggest an understanding of what the verse is saying (in context of the Psalm, hopefully), that explains what all these meanings are and how they fit?
Chag Sameach!
